# developing custom WSO2 Carbon authenticator clients

Tags: web-services, osgi, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am implementing new authentication methods for WSO2 Carbon. I know there is a pretty good explanation and sample piece of code in this [post](http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/carbon-authentication-framework.html).

The problem is, what if I want to generate stub and service client components from the sample BE authenticator? What are the steps to follow? Any tools (java2wsdl / wsdl2java, maven plugins,...) or reference tutorial that can help to achieve this in the most straightforward way?

I know there are several existing authenticators (IWA, webseal,...), but they already come with some stub/ui built in the existing repositories. I would be rather interested in being able to develop/generate all the components more or less from scratch rather than having to modify existing code, which is often prone to errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some high level thing..  but hope this is useful.

1. 1st you can develop the BE component as OSGI bundle. Then you can deploy it in /repository/components/dropins directory.  Here you need to have a service.xml file to  expose as web service (Please refer WebSeal BE component)
2. Then configure following property in the carbon.xml file..  if BE service has been defined as admin service
   true
3. Open browser and locate your  WSDL of new service

> https://{ip}:{port}/services/{service name}.wsdl

1. Then  use wsdl2java tool to create the stub class for you.  There is a UI tool in WSO2AS product to do it.
2. Use stub as a dependency for your FE

Comment: Thanks that helped. Although I only managed to get a zipped pom.xml from the WSO2AS wsdl2java tool, so I have to figure out what I missed in order to actually generate the stub classes.